# Getting Timeout Issue in Airflow

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am getting SSH operator error timed out issue in Airflow. Initially I was not getting this issue but Now I am getting this issue continually

**Code**

```
xx = [
        SSHOperator(
            task_id=str(i),
            command="sh /home/ec2-user/rapid/dht/hi_policy/bin/filename.sh ",
            ssh_conn_id=SECRET_NAME,
            dag=dag,
            do_xcom_push=True,
        )
        for i in dbo_list_1
    ]
```

**Error**

```
[2022-08-22 10:16:03,760] {{taskinstance.py:1482}} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/providers/ssh/operators/ssh.py", line 109, in execute
    with self.ssh_hook.get_conn() as ssh_client:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/providers/ssh/hooks/ssh.py", line 240, in get_conn
    client.connect(**connect_kwargs)
  
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 349, in <lambda>
    retry_on_signal(lambda: sock.connect(addr))
socket.timeout: timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1138, in _run_raw_task
    self._prepare_and_execute_task_with_callbacks(context, task)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1311, in _prepare_and_execute_task_with_callbacks
    result = self._execute_task(context, task_copy)
  
    raise AirflowException(f"SSH operator error: {str(e)}")
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: SSH operator error: timed out
```

Comment: Did you try to open a connection with same creds in the `ssh_conn_id` from the same server where Airflow is deployed?

Comment: was changes in environment only. Issue has resolved by AWS team